# Как добавить текст в пустой блок TD?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, bs4

Я пытаюсь спарсить сайт с таблицей, в ячейках которой есть пропуски и они не как не парсятся:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.bestfightodds.com/#'
HEADERS = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux armv7l) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Raspbian Chromium/78.0.3904.108 Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36', 'accept':'*/*', 'cookie':'bfo_reqdesktop=true; bfo_odds_type=2'}

def get_html(url, params=None):
    
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r
    
        
def get_content(html):
     soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
         
     items= soup.find_all('tbody')
     odds = []
     for item in items:
         odds.append((
            item.find('tr', class_="even").text,
            item.find('tr', class_="odd").text
             ))
    
     print(odds)   
    
     for i in odds:
        qq = str(i)
        qq = qq.replace('-', '+')
        q1 = qq.split('+')
        #print(i)
        #print(q1)
        for j in q1: 
            if j[0:3].isdigit() == True:
                print(int(str(j[0:3]))/100+1)
            else:
                print(j)
       # j+=1        
     #print(int(qq[-12:-8])/100+1)# 2 keff

     print(len(odds))
         
def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        print('norm')
        
        get_content(html.text)
    else:
        print('Error')

parse()
```

Что сделать, чтобы добавить текст в пустой блок TD?

Comment: вы получаете ошибку на пустой ячейке? зачем "добавлять текст в блок td", поясните?

Comment: нет просто мне необходимо чтобы я получал какое-то значение например строка из 12 блоков, но текст есть только у 3 и мне при парсинге выдает +150-130, а надо 0 0 0 0 0 0 +150 0 -130 0 0 0 что-то такое

Comment: для удобства последующего сравнения с другим сайтом

Comment: в каждой строке tr найдите все ячейки td и берите оттуда text, если нет текста - добавьте 0

Comment: я это и хочу делать только не совсем понимаю как(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
r = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

tbodies = soup.find_all('tbody')

for tbody in tbodies:
    rows = tbody.find_all('tr')        # найти все строки в таблице
    for row in rows:
        tds = row.find_all('td')       # найти все ячейки в строке
        for td in tds:
            td_text = td.text if td.text else '0'
            print(td_text)
```

Если в ячейке нет текста, ничего не напечатает

Comment: а можно если он пустой выводился не пробел а 0 ?

Comment: и как-то их сортировать, как у меня было ('Calvin Kattar', 'Max Holloway')
2.5
2.45
2.5
2.5300000000000002
2.5
2.45
2.45
2.5
2.46
2.5
2.4
2.35
2.7
2.75
2.9
2.67
2.75
2.75
2.7
2.8899999999999997
2.7
2.95
2.7
2.75
('Roxanne Modafferi', 'Viviane Araujo')
3.55
3.54
3.53
3.63
3.5
3.3
3.65
3.6
3.55
3.0
3.4
3.5
4.1
4.23
4.38
4.02
4.33
4.0
4.15
4.45
4.17
3.85
4.2
4.5

Comment: все можно, добавил: td_text = td.text if td.text else '0'

Comment: про сортировку у меня все добалялось в массив типа: имя потом кэфы

Comment: типа имена записаны в th

Comment: распарсьте отдельно строки с even и odd (rows = tbody.find_all('tr', class_='even')), соберите в списки, потом zip этих списков в результат... да, и имя спортсмена возьмите из span: name = row.find('span', class_='t-b-fcc').text